# Not getting complete response headers with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa-touch, afnetworking-2

I have started using `AFNetworking` just recently and facing issues in receiving response headers from JSON based server API. Below is the piece of code that I have written to talk to server. Request/Response is a JSON object.

**Issue:** When reading the response headers, I am not getting 2 additional security keys added by my server. When I use traditional `NSURLConnection` or new `NSURLSession` I am able to get them but `AFNetworking` API is not getting them back.

Any clue?

```
- (void)makeServerCall {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    // Set Request headers
    NSDictionary *securityHeaders = [MyUtilities securityRequestHeaders];

    for (NSString *headerKey in securityHeaders) {
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:securityHeaders[headerKey] forHTTPHeaderField:headerKey];
    }

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8"];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    // Make Server Call
    [manager POST:self.urlString parameters:self.postBody success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        if (!self.skipSecurityHeaders) {
            [MyUtilities securityResponseHeaders:[operation.response allHeaderFields]];
        }

        NSLog(@"Received response for %@ \n Response Header %@ \n Response %@", self.urlString, [operation.response allHeaderFields], responseObject);

        [self didFinishWithResult1:responseObject andResponse:operation.response];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

So, when I print `[operation.response allHeaderFields]`, I get following output:

```
Response Header {
    "Cache-Control" = "private, must-revalidate";
    "Content-Language" = "en-US";
    "Content-Length" = 929;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 02 May 2016 09:12:52 GMT";
    Pragma = private;
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Set-Cookie" = "NSC_JOuoxqqabim3ljwdrzxad5c42hiv0bf=ffffffff12a12ecc45525d5f4f58455e445a4a42378b;path=/;secure;httponly";
}
```

which is missing 2 additional keys - `key1` and `key2` sent by my server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out - I was setting headers before setting `requestSerializer`. So the flow should be -

```
- (void)makeServerCall {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8"];

    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    // Set Request headers
    NSDictionary *securityHeaders = [MyUtilities securityRequestHeaders];

    for (NSString *headerKey in securityHeaders) {
        [manager.requestSerializer setValue:securityHeaders[headerKey] forHTTPHeaderField:headerKey];
    }

    RUNNERLOG(@"Executing request for %@ \n Request Header %@ \n Request Body %@", self.urlString, securityHeaders, self.postBody);

    // Make Server Call
    [manager POST:self.urlString parameters:self.postBody success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nonnull operation, id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
        if (!self.skipSecurityHeaders) {
            [MyUtilities securityResponseHeaders:[operation.response allHeaderFields]];
        }

        NSLog(@"Received response for %@ \n Response Header %@ \n Response %@", self.urlString, [operation.response allHeaderFields], responseObject);

        [self didFinishWithResult1:responseObject andResponse:operation.response];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * _Nullable operation, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```